# Как вывести текст с определенной строки? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, argv

Есть код:

```
import sys

def read_prises(arg):
    with open('prises.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as p:
        p_lines = p.read()
        if len(arg) == 1: 
            print(p_lines)
        if len(arg) == 2:
            for i in range(int(arg[1])):
                print(p.readline(i))
            #Проблема вот в этом if-условии. Это все, что мне удалось сделать.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_prises(sys.argv)
```

Он должен возвращать текст из определенного файла.

Если в функцию будет передан аргумент в виде числа, то это число будет соответствовать номеру строки, с которой нужно будет печатать текст.

Я не знаю как это сделать. Все попытки приводили к тому, что выводилась пустота.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать!

Comment: Полный дубликат вопроса: [При чтении файла выводится пустота. Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1367156/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-python) Автор даже не читает коментарии.

Comment: Да, но мне было понятно не все, и комментариев было мало, по причине того, что я задал вопрос слишком поздно.

Comment: Тогда я закрою тот вопрос как дубликат этого. По поводу "задал вопрос слишком поздно" - достаточно внести в вопрос любую правку, тогда он поднимется на главной странице сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

**main.py**

```
import sys

def read_prises(arg):
    #print(f'arg = {arg}') 
    if len(arg) < 2:
        return
    
    num_line = int(arg[1])
    
    with open('prises.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as p:
        p_lines = p.read().split('\n')
        if num_line <= len(p_lines):
            print(f'Строка номер:{num_line} \n{p_lines[num_line]}' ) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_prises(sys.argv)
```

**prises.txt**

```
Он должен возвращать текст из определенного файла.
Если в функцию будет передан аргумент в виде числа, 
то это число будет соответствовать номеру строки, 
с которой нужно будет печатать текст. 
Я не знаю как это сделать. 
Все попытки приводили к тому, что выводилась пустота.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать!
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]